# How to display IEnumerable data grouped id in html datatable view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-table, view, ienumerable

I have a data table and need to group the values because just one column (Paxs) has no repeated data, the others data is expected to show in one line.

It´s so:
[Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvfil.png)

And should be:
[Should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENwll.png)

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
        <caption>Serviços</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Código</th>
            <th>Descrição Resumida</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Identificador Reserva</th>
            <th>Paxs</th>
            @*<th>Documentos Anexados</th>
              <th></th>
              <th>CTB</th>
              <th>Comercial</th>
              <th>Site</th>*@
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          @foreach (var itemServico in Model.Servicos.Take(10))
          {
            <tr>
              <td>@itemServico.CodServico</td>
              <td>@itemServico.DescTipo</td>
              <td>@itemServico.StatusReserva</td>
              <td>@itemServico.IdentReserva</td>
              <td>@itemServico.PaxsReserva</td>
              <td>
                <table>
                  @foreach (var itemFileIntra in Model.ServicoDocs)
                  {
                    <tr>
                      <td>@itemFileIntra.NomeArquivo</td>
                      <td>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                          <button aria-hidden="false" class="md-icon-button 
                              md-accent md-button md-ink-ripple">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                          </button>
                          <button aria-hidden="false" class="md-icon-button 
                              md-accent md-button md-ink-ripple">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                          </button>
                          <button aria-hidden="false" class="md-icon-button 
                              md-accent md-button md-ink-ripple">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
                          </button>
                        </span>
                      </td>
                      <td>@itemFileIntra.CTB</td>
                      <td>@itemFileIntra.COM</td>
                      <td>@itemFileIntra.Site</td>
                    </tr>
                  }
                </table>
              </td>

            </tr>
          }
        </tbody>
```

One column has different data, the others data is expected to show in one line.

Comment: you should computing your data in second foreach and put it your final data in for example viewbag or viewdata or variable and after second foreach use just one td like to other td in first foreach

Comment: You don't show your model, but this probably gets easier if you define a model class that lines up with what you want to show. Perhaps `Paxs` is a parent object and the corresponding rows are children. If you're starting from a different model, map it to your new one. It's much easier to create and map that model in code, and then your view doesn't get complicated. It naturally follows what's in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier if you create a model that reflects the data you want to display. That way the manipulation takes place in code, and the view just follows what's in the model.

This is not the most elegant example. Consider it an illustration.

You have this:

```
public class TheModelYouHave
{
    public string Servico { get; set; }
    public string DescTipo { get; set; }
    public string StatusReserva { get; set; }
    public string IdentReserva { get; set; }
    public string PaxsReserva { get; set; }
}
```

What you want is this:

```
public class TheModelYouWant
{
    public Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<TheModelYouHave>> ModelsGroupedByPaxsReserva { get; } 
        = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<TheModelYouHave>>();
}
```

It's a dictionary. The key is each distinct value of `PaxsReserva` and the value is a set of all of the items that have the same value for `PaxsReserva`.

To map the model you have to the one you want:

```
public static TheModelYouWant ToTheModelYouWant(IEnumerable<TheModelYouHave> source)
{
    var grouped = source.GroupBy(src => src.PaxsReserva, src => src);
    var result = new TheModelYouWant();
    foreach(var group in grouped)
        result.ModelsGroupedByPaxsReserva.Add(group.Key, group);
    return result;
}
```

Now in your view:

```
@foreach(var paxs in Model.ModelsGroupedByPaxsReserva.Keys)
```

and then to get the individual models that belong with that key:

```
var items = Model.ModelsGroupedByPaxsReserva[paxs];
```

(I call it `items` because I don't know what these things are.)